# navigate between images with imagemagick `display`

Tags: imagemagick

using imagemagick `display` CLI utility I can do

```
display *.png
```

But it only displays the first image and I don't now how to cycle between images.
Is there a keyboard shortcut ?
I tried arrows pgup / pgdwn etc. without success and the `man` doesn't provide any information about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press space to see the next image, backspace to see the previous image.

You can read about the keyboard shortcuts by pressing

> leftmouse->help->overview

.

Comment: i think unfortunately it the only place to look for `display` shortcuts (keyboard accelerators are not mentioned in `display.html` local documentation or on website), and that while the help screen is active it is impossible to try out the shortcuts on the image being displayed (or copy the help text).

Comment: They're in `display.html`, [here](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/display.html#keyb).